# looping array with key for a modal/div

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel

I've created a list of items that have an icon next to them where I'm trying to click the icon and have it populate a modal that contains the information, and this will be used to delete/edit things as I add to them.

The issue is that now when I click the icon it doesn't seem to pop up any modal at all. Before I added the `$key` it at least triggered a modal but each one had the info for the first item in the array. Now I"m simply trying to add a key to the necessary item so that if I click the icon I get a modal with only the info for that item.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
@foreach($nodes as $key => $node)   
    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
        <div class="uk-grid ">
            <div class="uk-width-2-6">
            {{$node->id}} - {{$node->name}}
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-2-6 ">
                <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
                 <a href="#edit-edit-modal{{ $key }}" data-uk-modal><span class="uk-icon-button"></span></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach


@foreach($nodes as $key => $node)
<div id="edit-edit-modal{{ $key }}" class="uk-modal">  
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
            <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                    {{$node->id}} - {{$node->name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-2-10 testComment">
                        <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: no javascript? did you check the console?

Comment: also, what is the final html like, did key come through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both divs in one foreach

```
@foreach($nodes as $key => $node)   
<div class="uk-width-1-1">
    <div class="uk-grid ">
        <div class="uk-width-2-6">
        {{$node->id}} - {{$node->name}}
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-2-6 ">
            <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
             <a href="#edit-edit-modal{{ $key }}" data-uk-modal><span class="uk-icon-button"></span></a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="edit-edit-modal{{ $key }}" class="uk-modal">  
   <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <div class="uk-width-1-1">
            <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                {{$node->id}} - {{$node->name}}
                </div>
                <div class="uk-width-2-10 testComment">
                    <span>{{ $node->comment }}</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```